# How to invoke methods with ref/out params using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Imagine I have the following class:

```
class Cow {
    public static bool TryParse(string s, out Cow cow) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to call `TryParse` via reflection? I know the basics:

```
var type = typeof(Cow);
var tryParse = type.GetMethod("TryParse");

var toParse = "...";

var result = (bool)tryParse.Invoke(null, /* what are the args? */);
```

Comment: This is precisely the question I was about to ask, even down to the method name :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var method = typeof (Cow).GetMethod("TryParse");
    var cow = new Cow();           
    var inputParams = new object[] {"cow string", cow};
    method.Invoke(null, inputParams); 
    // out parameter value is then set in inputParams[1]
    Console.WriteLine( inputParams[1] == null ); // outputs True
}

class Cow
{
    public static bool TryParse(string s, out Cow cow) 
    {
        cow = null; 
        Console.WriteLine("TryParse is called!");
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that: a) You don't need a 'Cow' instance for Invoking the TryParse method, you can just pass a value of null. b) the parsed 'Cow' is returned in inputParams[1], the 'cow' in the code above remains unchanged.

Comment: And therefore this was the answer, +1 all round.