# Reflection on a static overloaded method using an out parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, static-methods

I'm having some issues with invoking an overloaded static method with an out parameter via reflection and would appreciate some pointers.

I'm looking to dynamically create a type like `System.Int32` or `System.Decimal`, and then invoke the static `TryParse(string, out x)` method on it.

The below code has two issues:

- `t.GetMethod("TryParse", new Type[] { typeof(string), t } )` fails to return the MethodInfo I expect
- `mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { value.ToString(), concreteInstance })` appears to succeed but doesn't set the out param `concreteInstance` to the parsed value

Interwoven into this function you can see some temporary code demonstrating what should happen if the `type` parameter was set to `System.Decimal`.

```
public static object Cast(object value, string type)
{
    Type t = Type.GetType(type);
    if (t != null)
    {
        object concreteInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        decimal tempInstance = 0;

        List<MethodInfo> l = new List<MethodInfo>(t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public));

        MethodInfo mi;
        mi = t.GetMethod("TryParse", new Type[] { typeof(string), t } );  //this FAILS to get the method, returns null
        mi = l.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "TryParse" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2);  //ugly hack required because the previous line failed
        if (mi != null)
        {
            try
            {
                bool retVal = decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out tempInstance);
                Console.WriteLine(retVal.ToString());       //retVal is true, tempInstance is correctly set
                object z = mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { value.ToString(), concreteInstance });
                Console.WriteLine(z.ToString());            //z is true, but concreteInstance is NOT set
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return concreteInstance;
    }

    return value;
}
```

What do I need to do to ensure that my `t.GetMethod()` call returns the correct MethodInfo? What do I need to do to have `concreteInstance` correctly set in my  `mi.Invoke()` call?

I know there are a bunch of questions on this topic, but most of them involve static generic methods or static methods that are not overloaded. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304745/how-to-invoke-methods-with-ref-out-params-using-reflection) is similar but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to use the right `BindingFlags` and use `Type.MakeByRefType` for `out` and `ref` parameters. One second, and I'll have a code sample for you.

For example,

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(int).GetMethod(
    "TryParse",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
    Type.DefaultBinder,
    new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int).MakeByRefType() },
    null
);
```

I should point out that invoking this is a little tricky too. Here's how you do it.

```
string s = "123";
var inputParameters = new object[] { "123", null };
methodInfo.Invoke(null, inputParameters);
Console.WriteLine((int)inputParameters[1]);
```

The first `null` is because we are invoking a static method (there is no object "receiving" this invocation). The `null` in `inputParameters` will be "filled" for us by `TryParse` with the result of the parse (it's the `out` parameter).