# How do you call a generic method with out parameters by reflection?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Suppose I have a class like this, containing a generic method with an out parameter:

```
public class C
{
    public static void M<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence, out T result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        result = default(T);
    }
}
```

From reading the answers to a couple of other questions ([How to use reflection to call generic Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method) and [Reflection on a static overloaded method using an out parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740510/reflection-on-a-static-overloaded-method-using-an-out-parameter)), I thought I might be able to invoke the method via reflection as follows:

```
// get the method
var types = new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<int>), typeof(int).MakeByRefType() };
MethodInfo mi = typeof(C).GetMethod(
    "M", BindingFlags.Static, Type.DefaultBinder, types, null);

// convert it to a generic method
MethodInfo generic = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(int) });

// call it
var parameters = new object[] { new[] { 1 }, null };
generic.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

But `mi` is coming back null. I've tried using `object` instead of `int` in the `types` array but that doesn't work either.

How can I specify the types (needed for the out parameter) for a generic method *before* the call to `MakeGenericMethod`?

Comment: Does your real class have overloads of `M`? If not, you could just use the `GetMethod` variant where you don't need to specify the parameter types. That doesn't answer the question you asked though.

Comment: In this specific case I'll be able to work around it by not specifying any types and just using the name, as @SLaks suggested. I'm still interested to know what the syntax is for specifying an array of template types, or if it's not possible.

Comment: Where I was going wrong was that I thought it was necessary to pass the type array in order to use `out` or `ref` parameters. That's not the case... as long as you've got the correct `MethodInfo` by some means, you can pass it the parameter array and it will set the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm still interested to know what the syntax is for specifying an array of template types, or if it's not possible

[I don't think it's possible to pass that kind of detailed type specification to `GetMethod[s]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17570998). I think if you have a number of such `M`s to look through, you have to get them all and then filter by the various properties of the `MethodInfo`s and contained objects, eg as much of this as is necessary in your particular case:

```
var myMethodM =
    // Get all the M methods
    from mi in typeof(C).GetMethods()
    where mi.Name == "M"

    // that are generic with one type parameter
    where mi.IsGenericMethod
    where mi.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1
    let methodTypeParameter = mi.GetGenericArguments()[0]

    // that have two formal parameters
    let ps = mi.GetParameters()
    where ps.Length == 2

    // the first of which is IEnumerable<the method type parameter>
    where ps[0].ParameterType.IsGenericType
    where ps[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)
    where ps[0].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == methodTypeParameter

    // the second of which is ref <the method type parameter>
    where ps[1].ParameterType.IsByRef
    where ps[1].ParameterType.GetElementType() == methodTypeParameter

    select mi;
```

Answer (score 4):

This will let you call the method:

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(C).GetMethod("M");
MethodInfo generic = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(int) });
var parameters = new object[] { new[]{1},null};
generic.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

And to get the out parameter:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)parameters[1]); //will get you 0(default(int)).
```

Comment: Yes SLaks i know and your right as always :),i just presented this since OP didnt mention anything else besides this one only method,i know its a very "distinct"(lol) solution.

Answer (score 3):

You've passed parameters that will find `M<T>(IEnumerable<int>, ref int)`.
You need to find `M(IEnumerable<T>, ref T)` (the distinction between `ref` and `out` exists only in the C# language; reflection only has `ref`).

I'm not sure how to pass that; you may need to loop through all methods to find it.

On an unrelated note, you need to pass more `BindingFlags`:

```
BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static
```

Comment: It isn't clear from your answer, but the difference between `ref` and `out` should not matter here, it's only the generic type that should matter.

Comment: @hvd: Yes; I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known-problem; to find the method, you need to know its type parameter, but you can't know its type parameter without knowing the method first...

An obvious but inelegant solution is to loop through all methods until you find the right one.

Another option is to take advantage of the Linq Expression API:

```
public static MethodInfo GetMethod(Expression<Action> expr)
{
    var methodCall = expr.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    if (methodCall == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Expression body must be a method call expression");
    return methodCall.Method;
}


...

int dummy;
MethodInfo mi = GetMethod(() => C.M<int>(null, out dummy));
```