# Testing using reflection (PrivateObject)

Tags: c#, .net, testing, reflection, ref

I have a minor but rather annoying problem.

I am doing some tests using a PrivateObject to access various methods in a class. This all works fine. However when the method signature contains "ref" the ref keyword does not seem to have any effect.

```
private bool NewDeviceArrivedDeviceAtWorkcenter(ThreadStartArgs args, ref Device deviceAtStation)
{
//..SomeCode
     deviceAtStation = null;
//...Method to test
}
```

This test is failing..

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void CheckForDeviceAtWorkcenterNoDeviceFound()
        {
Initialization omitted

var device = new Device();

            var result = accessor.Invoke("NewDeviceArrivedDeviceAtWorkcenter", 
                new []
                    {
                        typeof (ThreadStartArgs), 
                        typeof (Device).MakeByRefType()
                    }, 
                    new object[] 
                    {
                        threadStartArgs, 
                        device
                    });

            Assert.IsNull(device);
}
```

Question: Why is device obj in the test method not set to null?

Any help appreciated

Kind Regards
Carsten

Answer (score 1):

The return is made through the argument array passed into the Invoke.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckForDeviceAtWorkcenterNoDeviceFound()
{ 
   //Initialization omitted for publicObject, threadStartArgs, device

   Type[] myTypes = new Type[] {typeof (ThreadStartArgs), 
                                typeof (Device).MakeByRefType() };
   object[] myArgs = new object[] { threadStartArgs, device };
   string sMethod = "NewDeviceArrivedDeviceAtWorkcenter";

   //Invoke method under test
   bool bResult = (bool)publicObject.Invoke(sMethod, myTypes, myArgs);

   Device returnDevice = (Device)myArgs[1];

   Assert.IsNull(returnDevice);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304745/how-to-invoke-methods-with-ref-out-params-using-reflection) reply you should get the MethodInfo of the method you want to test and invoke it just with the parameters array.

Have you tried invoking the method just with `typeof(Device)`, without the `MakeByRefType()` call?